# Put relativelayout at bottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I try to put my google admob at the bottom of the screen, but it appears to be pushed of. I searched for it and suggestions are to put it in a relativelayout and align it to parentbottom. I did this, but it doesn't appear to work.. Is my general structure wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#25ab89"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearBack"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBackButton"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScoreBoard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="level"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="0/30"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="score:"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12dp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" >
    </GridView>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a150be111791eae"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#25ab89"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" 
        android:id="@+id/llOneTop">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearBack"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBackButton"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScoreBoard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="level"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="0/30"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScoreInfoTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="score:"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12dp" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llOneTop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" >
    </GridView>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a150be111791eae"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i guess this should work  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: I have this in my <com.google.ads.adView but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that your root layout should be a `RelativeLayout`, then you can set your banner's `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Right now the `AdView` has a `RelativeLayout` parent which is still inside a `LinearLayout`. Hope this is clear.

Comment: one thing, my gridview now appears behind the google admob, any idea how to fix this? :s

Comment: @MatthiasVanb, Set some alignment to the GridView too, relative to parent or to other Views.

Comment: adding android:layout_below="@+id/llOneTop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout" to gridview doesn't fix it, it is still behind the ad..

Comment: @MatthiasVanb, Sorry, can't help you much without having the code. Try different alignment attributes, it should work if implemented properly.

Comment: I think the problem is that the gridview fills the height and that the relativelayout appears to be a layer over it... I updated my code..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26615/discussion-between-egor-and-matthias-vanb)